# With what info can attacker gain access to my Apple Id?

Tags: apple-id

I want to be sure how secure Apple is.

What does third malicious party need to gain access to my Apple account?
Can it only be done if they know by password or security questions (those are all well guarded)?

If malicious side has the email address name I use for my Apple account and as my Apple Id, they know my log in (admin name, only one account in Mac) name, street name, country, postal code and such things, they won't be able to gain access, right? Basically the info I have in my App Shop account information page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you enabled two step verification? If not that would be the first thing I do after reading this. This makes it so if someone trys to sign into your account it sends a message to all the devices you have associated with your account, presenting you with the name of the device and the location of the device (based on IP)

Try to hack your own account, and find out the steps you need to gain access.

For me when I try to recover my password (the first step a hacker might take) it asks me to confirm my phone number. If you don't know your phone number you're out of luck. If you do know the phone number then it doesn't matter much anyways as a confirmation message is sent to your phone.

I also believe they cannot present your security questions without you not being logged in for 24 hours. That could be Google I'm thinking of though.

After that information here are a couple steps I would take if I was worried about security.

1. Enable two step verification.
2. Be sure you use a different password for your Apple Id than you do on any other account (good practice for everything anyway) Never give out your password, be sure to always confirm where you are on the web. Ex. "Google.com" not "Gooogle.com" (Even though this example doesn't work because Google owns both domains, you get the point)
3. Be sure you have access to the phone number and email address on file with your account.
4. Ensure the email you have listed for your Apple ID is secure, and uses it's own password as well so a hacker couldn't gain access to that either.
5. I would recommend using Gmail if you don't already use it with your Apple ID, as I find them to be the most secure email to use.

Don't worry too much, you're in good hands!

Comment: Gmail has 2-step authentication as well, for the ultimate in belt & suspenders security.

Comment: @Jakoo please mark my answer as correct if it helped you :)

Comment: @Dan Hergenreder It says "votes cast by less than 15 reputation are recorded but do not change the publicly displayed post score". Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to answer but, as much as I dislike doing so, it must be done with a question:

What does a hacker need to know?  **What information did you provide?**  That's what they need to know.

Comment: Do I get it right that hackers can get in with any bit of info then? Even with just knowing apple id username/email and city name/postal code? That is terrifying....

Comment: What you must understand is that when you provide data to Apple, Google, Microsoft, etc. it is used to validate who you are.  If that information must be given, it must be used by you.  If it can be used by you, it can be used by someone else.  Nothing is completely secure, but you can make it very difficult.